# Checking sha256 checksum

Tags: sha256sum

I was trying to check the authenticity of a download by using the shasum in ubuntu. I am unable to understand the syntax though.

The code below works

1. `echo "<sha-hash> *filename" | shasum -a 256 -c`

I wanted to know why are we putting a  "*"(asterisk) before the file name.
I also tried generating a file using

2. `shasum -a 256 filename > file.sha`
3. `shasum -a 256 -c file.sha`

The above code also works. When I opened the `file.sha` file, I saw

```
<hash> <filename>
```

There is no asterisk present in the file. I tried writing the first statement without asterisk, but then it throws an error stating

> shasum: standard input: no properly formatted SHA1 checksum lines found

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Putting an asterisk before the file name tells `shasum` to treat the file as binary if the system supports this. Id the file should be treated as text file you use a single blank instead.

Linux doesn't make a difference between binary and text files so it doesn't matter which one you use, but you can't leave it out.

So you have to use

```
<hash>  <filename>
```

with **two** blanks after the hash: One blank that separates the hash from the filename and one blank for text mode.